# How do I read the string from a Spinner selected event

Tags: android, spinner

I have a simple app where the user selects one of the US states and the state selected is to be used to list all of the counties in that state. In onCreate, I built an arrayadapter called Stateadapter, and set it to the spinner object "spinState". I then initialized a listener class StateOnItemSelectedListener. Outside of onCreate, I have the StateOnItemSelectedListener class that will read which State was selected in the spinner, and then perform the rest of the app's tasks.

I have two problems: when single stepping thru the code in debug mode, the "parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString" does not return the string value of the selected state (though numerous web examples suggest this should work).

Second, when running, the app fires the listener when going thru onCreate and all appears well until the user selects the spinner on the ui, and the app then does a force close.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{       
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    spinState = (Spinner)this.findViewById(R.id.spinState); 

    ArrayAdapter<String> Stateadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>                        (this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, array_spinState);
    Stateadapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);    
    spinState.setAdapter(Stateadapter);   

    spinState.setOnItemSelectedListener(new StateOnItemSelectedListener());

}   

public class StateOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener
{   
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View itemSelected,  int pos, long         id) 
    {   State = spinState.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
        //Do Stuff base on State;
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent)
    {   //Do nothing here 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Whats the error you are getting the logcat?

Comment: 12-11 16:24:47.040: I/global(664): Default buffer size used in BufferedReader constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k-char buffer is required.
12-11 16:24:52.279: D/AndroidRuntime(664): Shutting down VM
12-11 16:24:52.279: W/dalvikvm(664): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
12-11 16:24:52.309: E/AndroidRuntime(664): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-11 16:24:52.309: E/AndroidRuntime(664): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-11 16:24:52.309: E/AndroidRuntime(664):  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource

Answer (score 0):

Try doing what they do in the [Spinner Tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-spinner.html), they create the adapter in a different way, but eventually they use the same code to access to selected item and it works.

What is the error in log cat from the force close, and what `getItemAtPosition` *does* return?

Comment: State = spinState.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(); returns "String com.myApp.Main.State

Comment: sorry i left out the declarations...State is a string variable - String State;

Comment: That's weird... try doing `spinState.getItemAtPosition(pos).getClass()`, what class is the object you receive?